# Get bash read command prompt text from parent process

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash

I need to automate a few bash scripts which involves answering to `read` prompts with `y/n`.

I tried to pipe `stdout`/`stderr`/`stdin` to a python script. Writing to `stdin` works but reading the prompt text from `stdout`/`stderr` doesn't for some reason? (I can read everything else that bash or sub-processes output fine.)

```
>>> from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
>>> proc = Popen(['bash','-c','read -r -p "Update system? [y/N] " response'],stdout=PIPE,stdin=PIPE,stderr=PIPE)
>>> proc.stdout.read(10) # <-- hangs, same with stderr, any length
```

I was expecting I would be able to read displayed prompt `"Update system? [y/N] "` somehow so I can decide what answer to pass back.

Comment: As an aside, you might as well set `shell=True` and pass just the final string to the shell. The `read` prompt text will be on standard error, not standard output.

Comment: @tripleee hmm... still couldn't get it to work: `proc = Popen('read -r -p "test" abc',shell=True,stderr=PIPE,stdin=PIPE) proc.stderr.read(1) # <--- hangs`

Comment: Yeh, not an attempt to answer the question, just sort out some loose ends. I vaguely suspect your problem is related to buffering but I wasn't able to come up with any solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what `expect` is good at:

https://likegeeks.com/expect-command/

Expect and bash
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/351446/bash-and-expect-in-the-same-script

Comment: Omg, `autoexpect` does it all <3

Comment: Yep, `autoexpect` can be very helpful.  https://linux.die.net/man/1/autoexpect . good luck with your project